# Change column dimension and shorten too long names - Datatables

Tags: datatables

Datatables is a great tool but i don't know how you can do these 2 things:

- Add the option to manually change the size of the columns, drag them to the right or to the left to suit your needs.
- Shorten the too long text. But with Datatable the text wraps. In this way, however, the cell size increases. *And I do not want to get this effect*.

This is an example of how these 2 things are well integrated with the Firefox plugin "Downloadthemall":

[image]

---

[image]

**How can I do it?**

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin to make the table columns re-sizable.  Just grab the script and include it before table initialization, and after you include the datatables script.  Then when you initialize your datatable include the R in your sDom, ie:

```
"sDom": "Rlfrtip"
```

you can control the behavior of the wrapping with css.  Add a class to your table.

```
<style>
.myClass td {white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;}
</style>
```

Comment: But the script is inside file? To control the behavior of the wrapping with css i must edit demo_table_jui.css? Can u show me with some picture? I really don't understand so

Comment: no, just when you setup your table add the class:  <table class="myClass"> ... </table>    you can have multiple classes applied to a table, so the classes datatables adds will also be applied.

Comment: David, i undestand better if u have a demo. Can u help me, please?

Comment: I will build a demo tomorrow if I can find the time.

Comment: thank you David because when i try manipulate sDom the original layout change. I try also to add Colvis to hide something but both pagination and the number of enters disappears. I want preserve this layout http://chilp.it/bef90e but i want add to hide columns and make columns resizable. But is possible resize also entire table container also like this http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/?